# How to display a user’s published content on their account?

Tags: views, users, 9

Does anyone know how to display every article (or content type) a user has published on their "my account" view? To clarify, I only want it to display that specific user's published content so that all users can click on a user and then see all of that particular user's published content.

What I currently have set up so far is my account/user's view page setup and displays the user's username and ALL published content. Still, it isn't filtered by the specific user's account/ content, only if the content is published or not.

I've tried adding different filters, but none have worked for me. I've also tried adding a "username of the content author" relationship, but that still won't do the trick. If it's helpful, the view's URL is /user/* (* representing a different number depending on which user's account view you are on)

Update: I installed pathauto module and changed the view's URLs to /user/[username] (so if your username is "human," the URL is now /user/human)

Comment: I'm somewhat in a hurry. "Advanced / Contextual Filters", then choosing the Author/User ID field should do it. It will automatically use the User ID from URL contextual filter.

Comment: @MarioSteinitz thank you for the reply, there were a few different variations of this filter and I tried them all but it’s still not working properly

Comment: @ImagineSystem7 first we need to know what content your view is of. When you created the view in `/admin/structure/views/add` did you select "show: content" or "show: users"?

Comment: The trick is to configure the contextual filter (of the author ID) to `Provide default value` and set that to `User ID from route context`. You can search this site with these terms to find a more detailed example with more steps.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a view. Since you want it on the entity.user.canonical route, you need to create a block.

The view needs a contextual filter to use the user id from the URL path as a filter.

Next to **Contextual filters** click Add. Select 'Content: Authored By'.
In **When the filter is NOT in the URL** select 'Provide default value'. Set Type to 'User Id from route context'

[add a contextual filter to a view](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/views/add-a-contextual-filter-to-a-view)